# C# : How to convert string to DateTime, where the string can have any of the standard datetime format 

Tags: c#, datetime, string

I had posted a question on DateTime to String conversion, I got many satisfying answers for that .. so I thank StackOverflow very much ..
 Here is one more problem of String manupulation, I am stuck with ..
 I have to convert a string (from some external source) using C# code .. the string can have these expected format of DateTime ..

1. `02/31/2009 01:59:59`           24 hours format
2. `02/31/2009 01:59:59 AM`     12 hours format
3. `2/31/2009 1:59:59`
4. `2/31/2009 1:59:59 AM`
5. `02/01/2009 01:59:59 AM`
6. `2/1/2009 1:59:59`
7. and so on .......

I tried using `DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(string_date.Substring(6,4)),Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)` 
*ie, By extracting the values of month, Day etc*
But it doesn't work .. because I can't extract the values with substring perfectly .. as the length of string is  **Varying** 
 I also have tried to extract the values referring the occurance of "/", "*space*" and ":" but it becomes bottle neck to derive with (non-)Occurrence of AM/PM
 *Only the length of Day, Month and Hours can vary ..*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `DateTime.ParseExact` overload that takes a list of formats:

```
private static string[] formats = new string[]
    {
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
        "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
        "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss"        
    };

private static DateTime ParseDate(string input)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(input, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```

This will throw a `FormatException` if the passed string does not match any of the given formats. Notice that the formats expecting AM/PM should appear before identical formats without AM/PM (`"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"` comes before `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`).

**Update**
As [Henk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) points out in the comments, the same functionality is available when using `TryParseExact` which removes exception situation. Also, paired with nullable types this can be made a bit cleaner:

```
private static DateTime? ParseDate(string input)
{
    DateTime result;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now it will simply return a null reference if it fails to parse the input.

Comment: This overload also exists for TryParseExact, no reason to let it come to an exception.

Comment: @Henk: thanks. I expected that but didn't find it. I now realize that I was only looking at `TryParse`...

Comment: @Fredrik "return null" shows error .. as it is not type "DateTime"

Comment: @Aravind: note that the method in the last example has the return type `DateTime?` (note the question mark); this means that it is a nullable type, where `null` is a valid value.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method. Here's an example with the first case:

```
DateTime date;
// I changed 02/31/2009 to 01/31/2009 because the first is not a valid date
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("01/31/2009 01:59:59", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // string successfully parsed => do something with the date
}
```

You could then keep a list of different formats and try to parse the string with all of them until you succeed.

Comment: Is there any other EFFICIENT way .. ?
I mean its painful to type THOSE MANY LINES as many Lines I have as options ..

Answer (score 2):

Here are all the possible formats ..

> 1. MM/dd/yyyy   08/22/2006
> 2. dddd, dd MMMM yyyy  Tuesday, 22
>      August 2006
> 3. dddd, dd MMMM yyyy  HH:mm Tuesday,
>      22 August 2006 06:30
> 4. dddd, dd MMMM yyyy  hh:mm tt
>      Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30 AM
> 5. dddd, dd MMMM yyyy  H:mm Tuesday, 22
>      August 2006 6:30
> 6. dddd, dd MMMM yyyy  h:mm tt Tuesday,
>      22 August 2006 6:30 AM
> 7. dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
>       Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30:07
> 8. MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm  08/22/2006 06:30
> 9. MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt  08/22/2006
>      06:30 AM
> 10. MM/dd/yyyy H:mm  08/22/2006 6:30
> 11. MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss  08/22/2006
>        06:30:07
> 12. MMMM dd  August 22
> 13. yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
>         2006-08-22T06:30:07.7199222-04:00
> 14. ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
>         Tue, 22 Aug 2006 06:30:07 GMT
> 15. yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
>         2006-08-22T06:30:07
> 16. HH:mm  06:30
> 17. hh:mm tt  06:30 AM
> 18. H:mm  6:30
> 19. h:mm tt  6:30 AM
> 20. HH:mm:ss  06:30:07
> 21. yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z' 
>         2006-08-22 06:30:07Z
> 22. dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
>         Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30:07
> 23. yyyy MMMM  2006 August

Answer (score 0):

DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("2007/01/01 04:23:12", "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", 
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2007/01/01 04:23:12", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture 
format param