# DateTime conversion with Timezone information C#

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse DateTime with timezone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)

I have a datetime string = "10/09/2012 5:00 pm PST" How do I convert this into DateTime using DateTime.ParseExact(). I am looking for the literal that will match PST or EST.

Comment: Question already asked here: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/241789/1252575][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/241789/1252575

Comment: I don't think .NET supports timezone *names*, only *offsets*, e.g. -4:00

Comment: This can also help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886444/c-sharp-how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-where-the-string-can-have-any-of-th

Comment: I saw the post. But, is there any other elegant option. I do not have a mapping of all Timezone and the Timezone offset.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net

Answer (score 0):

Replace the PST with the UTC offset, I think it should work:

```
string value = "10/09/2012 5:00 pm PST";
value = value.Replace ("PST", "−8");

DateTime.ParseExact (value, "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt z", Culture....);
```